# Is a determinant multilinear in multiple rows at the same time?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

So I know that a determinant is a multilinear function, now the question is if the equation is true. $$\det\begin{pmatrix} a+u &b+v  &c+w  \\ d+x& e+y & f+z \\l& m &n \end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c \\ d&e&f \\l&m&n \end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix} u&v&w \\ x&y&z \\l&m&n \end{pmatrix}$$
I thought maybe to check that if it's multilinear in 2 rows at the same time it's the same as doing the rows separate, if this is correct then the answer I found tells me that it's not multilinear in two rows at the same time. Could anyone confirm if my thinking is correct?

Comment: Expand out one row at a time.  You will the the sum of determinants of 4 matrices.

Comment: @user317176 Yes I did that and I found that it's not the same since u have 2 extra determinants, but since you made this comment I suppose my thinking is correct?

Comment: Take both matrices to be identity.

Comment: Or any two matrices such that the sum of your "2 extra determinants" is $\ne0.$ You can even chose the 3rd line to be for instance $(001).$

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is incorrect. The correct version is
$$
\begin{align}
\det\begin{pmatrix} a+u &b+v  &c+w  \\ d+x& e+y & f+z \\l& m &n \end{pmatrix}
&=
\det\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c \\ d&e&f \\l&m&n \end{pmatrix}
+
\det\begin{pmatrix} u&v&w \\ x&y&z \\l&m&n \end{pmatrix}
\\&\quad+
\det\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c \\ x&y&z \\l&m&n \end{pmatrix}
+
\det\begin{pmatrix} u&v&w \\ d&e&f \\l&m&n \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$